# Doctrine Query Builder IN clause with multiple values

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a User entity which has a ManyToMany relationship with companyType :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CompanyType")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $companyTypes;
```

And a Company entity which can have 0 or multiple types :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CompanyType", inversedBy="companies")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $companyTypes;
```

This creates a user_companyType table in my database.

**I want to build, with Doctrine queryBuilder, a query which returns if at least one element in u.companyTypes is in c.companyTypes.**

I can't find how to.

Here's what I've tried :

```
$userCompanyTypes = array();
foreach ($user->getCompanyTypes() as $companyType) {
    $userCompanyTypes[] = $companyType;
}

$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder('i')
->from(Invoice::class, 'i')
->leftJoin('i.account', 'a')
->leftJoin('i.company', 'c')
->leftJoin('c.companyTypes', 'ct')
->leftJoin('a.users', 'u')
->andWhere("c.companyTypes IN (:userCompanyTypes)") // ... search if there's a match 
->setParameter("userCompanyTypes", $userCompanyTypes);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Long story short :

- An account contains multiple users
- An invoice is always linked to an account AND a company
- A CompanyType is an Object, not a String
- The invoices I want to get are the ones linked to companies the user has right on (= the user has a companyType that the company itself has)

Is there anything else that I can use with the query builder to do this ?

Comment: try $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in("c.companyTypes'', $userCompanyTypes));

Comment: Well. The '... some where clause' is probably not helping.  You condensed your query just a bit too much for someone to help.  Update the question with the actual query.  Go ahead and just remove the [] completely if you want.  But give us a real query and verify that $userCompanyTypes is an array.

Comment: @Albeis No need to use expr's.  The andWhere clause shown in the question will work just fine assuming the rest of the query is correct.

Comment: Waiting for the full query then!

Comment: I updated the query with some more information, thank you for helping !

Comment: I got this error now : "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\\Entity\\CompanyType could not be converted to string". I forgot to mention that CompanyType is an Object.

Comment: Next step is to comment out the andWhere and setParameter and verify the rest of the query gives the expected results.  Mostly to double check your mapping.

Comment: When I comment the andWhere and setParameter, I indeed have the result that the query is supposed to return. With the above code, I get this : "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 436 near 'companyTypes': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected." I tried to wrap it with identity() but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't normally like to answer these sorts of question without setting up a test case.  Your error message is a bit odd but I'll give it a try.  I know that the IN clause will work with individual ids.  So maybe:

```
$userCompanyTypeIds = array();
foreach ($user->getCompanyTypes() as $companyType) {
    $userCompanyTypeIds[] = $companyType->getId();
}
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder('i')
->select('count(DISTINCT i.id)')
->from(Invoice::class, 'i')
->leftJoin('i.account', 'a')
->leftJoin('i.company', 'c')
->leftJoin('c.companyTypes', 'ct')
->leftJoin('a.users', 'u')
->andWhere("ct.id IN (:userCompanyTypeIds)") // ... search if there's a match 
->setParameter("userCompanyTypeIds", $userCompanyTypeIds);

$count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Should at least get you a step further.  Updated the answer showing how to get a total count.  Never been a big fan of using the expr class even though it is quite common.

Comment: I can see progress in my code, it all makes sense, but :
let's say i want to count my results, i added $qb->select($qb->expr()->count('distinct(i.id)')); --- 
without the last andWhere and setParameter, I end up with a working query. With it, In my error logs, I see "SELECT FROM" (without anything after SELECT)

Comment: Updated the answer with count syntax.

Comment: It finally worked with the last update ! Thank you for your help @Cerad :)